# R - How to order list by ascending/descending frequency?

Tags: r

I have a categorical variable with 191 unique values (smartphone models). How do I create a list or data frame that orders these model names in ascending/descending order by frequency?

Here's an example of the first few rows of the Model variable.

```
table(full2$Model)


             10                 105                  3T              5 Plus 
             19                   1                   5                   9 
             5T                   6                   8                  A1 
             19                   1                   8                   2 
          A3003                  A5                  A9              AXON 7 
              1                   1                   2                   1 
     Black Moon                Bolt            Convoy 3            Cosmos 3 
             21                   1                   2                   5 
     Desire 610          Desire 625             Droid 2         Droid Turbo 
              6                   1                   1                  63
```

Ultimately, I need only the top X number of models.

Comment: Not clear without a reproducible example and expected output

Comment: @akrun Updated with an example. I don't have a specific expected output, so long as I'm able to see which models are most frequent.

Answer (score 3):

You can use table() for this

```
sort(table(full2$Model))
```

To get the first 10 entries:

```
sort(table(full2$Model))[1:10]
```

To reverse sort order:

```
sort(table(full2$Model), decreasing=TRUE)[1:10]
```